# Screencast to a TV through a Roku

Tags: tv, screencast

I have an ubuntu 14.04 box, Roku 3 and 50 inch TV and I want to cast my pc screen to the TV. The roku and pc are on the same network. Has anyone got a way to do this? Doesn't have to be a nice solution, just wondering if it's possible.

Comment: Currently I am unaware that any roku device can screencast

Comment: I would also like to stream my ubuntu 14.04 desktop to my Roku
It works with windows and android but not Ubuntu yet :-(
http://support.roku.com/entries/56266670-Roku-screen-mirroring-overview

Comment: MicacleCast does not allow Linux to be the source. Only the sink.

Answer (score 2):

Check out MiracleCast.

This might be what you're looking for. It projects your screen onto TV's using Miracast over WiFi.

https://github.com/albfan/miraclecast
https://launchpad.net/~thopiekar/+archive/ubuntu/miraclecast