# Ubuntu 20.04 screen sharing -- what do I run on Roku to view it?

Tags: dlna, desktop-sharing

If I enable the built-in screen sharing on Ubuntu 20.04 (or any other version with built-in screen sharing), how can I view that share from a Roku device? Do I need to run some app on the Roku? What app?

Comment: I probably should have said 18+ since I mean whenever Screen Sharing became an official feature.

Comment: Do you want to mirror your display in a TV? Or do you want to share your screen with someone in another city, or country to show them what's on your screen?

Comment: I want to mirror it to my TV.

Comment: Assuming your computer and your TV have HDMI sockets, you can connect the two using a HDMI cable. There is no easy way to connect them wirelessly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Screencast to a TV through a Roku](https://askubuntu.com/questions/554496/screencast-to-a-tv-through-a-roku)

Comment: So what is the built-in screen sharing for if I have to run Mirclecast to share my screen?

Comment: The built in screen sharing is for my grandfather who lives away from me to share the screen with me, so that I can see what's on the screen and help him with the problem he is having with Ubuntu. I can also control his computer with this feature. See https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/sharing-desktop.html.en